# There is an error in the class do not understand written with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I get the following error when I want to run this code. I made a mistake I do not understand where all the normal

Where do you think the error

```
import socket,time
import thread

    class http():

        def __init__(self):
            self.socket = socket
            self.port = 5000
            self.buffsize = 1024
            self.listen = 5
            self._header = ("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
                            "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n")

        def _worker(self,socket,sleep):
            # Client connect for thread worker
            while True:
                time.sleep(sleep)
                client,address = socket.accept()
                data = client.recv(1024)
                if data:
                    client.send(self._header)
                    client.send(data)
                client.close()

        def httpHandler(self):
            # Create Socket For Connection
            try:
                self.socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                self.socket.bind(('127.0.0.1',self.port))
                self.socket.listen(self.listen)
                self.socket.setblocking(False)
            except socket.error as error:
                print error
            finally:
                print "HTTP Server Running - 127.0.0.1:5000"
                self._worker(self.socket,1)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        application = http()
        application.httpHandler()
```

When I want to run on the terminal, the error

but how can it be said there is the problem of self-

```
HTTP Server Running - 127.0.0.1:5000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/batuhangoksu/http.py", line 44, in <module>
    application.httpHandler()
  File "/Users/batuhangoksu/http.py", line 40, in httpHandler
    self._worker(self.socket,1)
  File "/Users/batuhangoksu/http.py", line 22, in _worker
    client,address = socket.accept()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'accept'
```

Comment: use a different variable name for the local variable `socket`

Comment: `self.socket = socket` ... this is ridiculous

Comment: @Matthias Please be nice. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/

Comment: `self.socket = socket` ... this is unusual/strange

Answer (score 2):

Use `self.socket`, not `socket`:

```
            client,address = self.socket.accept()
```

`socket` is the name of the module. `self.socket` is a `socket._socketobject`, the value returned by a call to `socket.socket`. Verily, there are too many things named "socket" :).
I suggest changing `self.socket` to something else to help separate the ideas.

---

You also need to save the return value when you call `socket.socket`. Currently, you have

```
self.socket = socket
```

which sets the instance attribute `self.socket` to the module `socket`. That's not useful, since you can already access the module with plain old `socket`. Instead, use something like

```
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

---

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import socket
import time

HOST = ''           # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 50007        # Arbitrary non-privileged port

def server():
    header = ("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
              "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n")
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen(5)
    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        if not data: break
        conn.send(header)
        conn.send(data)
        conn.close()

def client():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.send('Hello, world')
    data = s.recv(1024)
    s.close()
    print 'Received', repr(data)

sproc = mp.Process(target = server)
sproc.daemon = True
sproc.start()
while True:
    time.sleep(.5)
    client()
```